# Scrollable Divs inside web page independent from main scroll

Tags: css, html, scroll

I have a series of scrollable divs on a page. When a DIV gets scrolled to say the top and the user keeps scrolling it starts to scroll the page up instead (not so much on Firefox) but on Safari and Chrome it does.

This is annoying, and I notices that on Facebook, the activity monitor, friends online and chat window do not do this. If your mouse is in the div the you can only scroll that div not the page when you reach the top or bottom.

How have they done this?

Marvellous

Answer (score -1):

Facebook use a custom scrollbar instead of those that come with the browser (at least, for the friends online sidebar).

Custom made controller = custome made control. :)

Comment: I'm not sure about that as in Safari on Lion it uses the native looking scrollbar, in Chrome it uses the the chrome one and in Firefox the firefox one. I do not believe your answer is correct. If it were to be scrollbar could not look and function in the way that it does.

Comment: Maybe we were not talking about the same scrollbar... I've look at the chat window scrollbar in facebook (on firefox) and it does start scrolling the page __if you keep scrolling__. The same happened in a test page I made. However, the results were quite not the same in Opera. Now, I'm puzzled too!